# calculating the next state of an observation

Tags: r, markov-chains, binomial-cdf

I´m trying to calculate the next state from a given probability vector extracted from a transition matrix.

```
probs <- structure(c(0.876896837675484, 0.101918293545303, 0.0189210190005101, 
0.00220982524291829, 5.40245357842536e-05), .Names = c("State 1", 
"State 2", "State 3", "State 4", "State 5"))
```

Where probs stands for the probability vector, the next step is to calculate the output given a binomial distribution.

```
set.seed(1)
rbinom(n = 5,size = 1,prob = probs)
```

Where n is number of observations (in this case state 1 --> State 5), size is number of trials (1 success or 0 failed) and prob is the probability of success of each observation and the function returns the following output:

```
1,0,0,0,0
```

So I'm assuming that the more probable ouput is the state 1 after one step, but sometimes I get the following:

```
1,0,1,0,0
```

But that wouldn't be possible because the person should only go to a certain state from his previous step.

Anyone has an idea on how to solve this?

Thanks for your time

Solved:
I should have used rmultinom instead of rbinom

Answer (score 0):

The `rbinom` function does not compute transitions in a Markov process. It delivers a random draw from a universe of possibilities with a particular probability. If you wanted a single run of a 5-state transition process where there were 5 items in state-1 at the start, you would create a vector of starting values c(5,0,0,0,0). Then you would specify a transition matrix where the probabilities for all possible transitions were specified. It would need to be a 5x5 matrix in this case. Your vector of probabilities could be the first row, which would then be the probabilities for going from state-1 to any other state in the next interval in time. But you also need to state what the probabilities for transitions *from* the other states might be. If they are absorbing states then their i-th element would be 1 so this might be the matrix:

```
  trans <- matrix( c(0.876896837675484, 0.101918293545303, 0.0189210190005101, 0.00220982524291829, 5.40245357842536e-05,

                     0,1,0,0,0,
                     0,0,1,0,0,
                     0,0,0,1,0,
                     0,0,0,0,1), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE, dimnames= list( from=c("State 1", 
"State 2", "State 3", "State 4", "State 5") , to = c("State 1", 
"State 2", "State 3", "State 4", "State 5") ))

trans
         to
from        State 1   State 2    State 3     State 4      State 5
  State 1 0.8768968 0.1019183 0.01892102 0.002209825 5.402454e-05
  State 2 0.0000000 1.0000000 0.00000000 0.000000000 0.000000e+00
  State 3 0.0000000 0.0000000 1.00000000 0.000000000 0.000000e+00
  State 4 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 1.000000000 0.000000e+00
  State 5 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.000000000 1.000000e+00
```

Now you could apply this to a starting (or successive) vector of counts. Then that result would be the next state in a sequence. It can be done with either a deterministic method of by making random draws.